# Drupal with Appearance is not able to see Theme - mystery

Tags: drupal

With Drupal I got a new Mac and I installed the Drupal item and went well.

However when I am looking at '**Appearance**' I can not see '**Install new theme**', it's not there, basically it's missing.

I have gone through a few things such as

> /sites/default/settings.php
>
> $settings['allow_authorize_operations'] = TRUE;

Also tried

> Administer modules permission

And nothing works! It has to do with MySQL possibly.

Can someone please help me. This is very frustrating.

[Missing 'Install new theme'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlOOw.png)

[Not there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrn7q.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Update Manager. Quote [from the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/extend-theme-install.html):

> **Site prerequisites**
> If you want to install via the website, the core Update Manager module must be installed.

1. Navigate to *Extend*
2. Enable *Update Manager*
3. Click on *Install*
4. Navigate to *Configuration* -> *Development* -> *Performance*
5. Click on *Clear all caches*

Now go back to *Appearance*. The Button is now there.